# Eclipse Editor Plugin: isSaveAsAllowed

Tags: java, eclipse, save, editor, eclipse-plugin

Working on my plugin for Eclipse containing among others a multi-page editor I faced a problem with the method `isSaveEnabled()` which is supposed to be overwritten in order to disable or enable the possibility to save the opened file. I forbid to change pages for certain conditions, so I've got the corresponding field and methods to achieve that:

```
public class ARTEditor
    extends FormEditor
    implements IResourceChangeListener
{
    private boolean pageChangeEnabled;

    @Override
    protected void pageChange(int newPageIndex)
    {
        if (pageChangeEnabled)
        {
            super.pageChange(newPageIndex);
            switch (newPageIndex)
            {
                // handling the change of the active page
            }
        }
    }

    // getter + setter for pageChangeEnabled used by other components
}
```

Now I would like to disable/enable the save action for the same conditions. I thought it would be sufficient to overwrite the above stated method:

```
@Override
public boolean isSaveAsAllowed()
{
    return pageChangeEnabled;
}
```

But this doesn't work, although the method correctly returns `true` or `false`. For testing I create the condition where I can't change pages, then press Ctrl+S and see that the file is saved because the asterisk showing the dirty state disappears.

Do I need to do anything else to implement my requirement?

**upd:**

A possible approach would be:

```
@Override
public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor)
{
    if (pageChangeEnabled)
    {
        // handle save action
    }
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is that the user can get confused: save action looks active but in fact it isn't.

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean? What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I updated the question to describe it more presicely. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isSaveAsAllowed` method is only used to determine if 'File > Save As...' can be used. It is not used for 'File > Save'.

If you don't want to allow 'File > Save' you could override:

```
public boolean isDirty()
```

and prevent the editor for reporting it is dirty. This will also prevent the '*' showing that the editor is dirty being displayed.

You may need to call `editorDirtyStateChanged()` when you change your `pageChangeEnabled` flag to get the editor to call `isDirty` again.

You could also override `doSave`, in this case you should call `setCanceled` on the progress monitor. You might also want to show a `MessageDialog` explaining why you are not doing the save.

Comment: I wouldn't like to affect the indication of dirty state, rather just to disable save button/action when `pageChangeEnabled` is set to `false`. I updated the question and added a possible solution.

Comment: I think a `MessageDialog` will resolve the problem. Thanks :)